# Vue copying of object to local data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to copy the data from a prop, to the local data() value for editing, **but it keeps editing both when I make a change.**

```
export default {
  props: {
    item: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      form: { ...this.item }
    }
  }
}
```

I then pass the Translations property of the local Form data to another component, which handles the editing

```
<tab
   v-for="translation in form.translations"
   :key="translation.locale.value"
   :name="translation.locale.value">
   <form-group :fields="translation" />
</tab>
```

In my FormGroup component, I receive the passed fields, filter them out so the hidden one's don't show up, and edit them.

**Now when I edit, I see in my Vue inspector that the original Item from my parent component is also getting edited.**

```
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    fields: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filtered () {
      return Object.keys(this.fields)
        .filter(field => this.fields[field].type !== 'hidden')
        .reduce((res, field) => Object.assign(res, { [field]: this.fields[field] }), {})
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
// Deep Clone, as per MDN web docs 
  obj1 = { a: 0 , b: { c: 0}};
  let obj3 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1));
  obj1.a = 4;
  obj1.b.c = 4;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj3)); // { a: 0, b: { c: 0}}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Objects are non-primitives, unlike Number, String, Boolean etc. This means that they are parsed by reference, and not value.

Therefor changes in a object, even across components and even if they are props, you are not actually changing the prop from the child, but from the parent, and the re-parsing the new version, as an updated version of the prop.

```
export default {
    props: {
        data: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        }
    },

    computed: {
        clonedData() {
            return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data))
        }
    }
}
```

**Read more on Reference vs. Value** https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0

Comment: Hmh, this is working, but it does seem hacky? Why does this work and my above code doesn't?

Comment: Because Objects are parsed as reference, unlike primitive types, such as Number, String, Boolean etc. So your changing the referenced Object. https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0

Comment: So what I need is a deep clone, right? Is it possible without the JSON methods?

Comment: Not to my knowledge mate, but I'll gladly admit im not an all knowing oracle ;) I've used Deep Watchers before, haven't heard of Deep Copy.

Comment: I meant deep clone, sorry, I ended up using lodash's cloneDeep method, which is now working perfectly, your solution works as well, except it will discard Function and Infinite types if present in the object.

Comment: Glad you found a solution! Then I actually learned something as well, didn't know that functions were discarded.

Comment: lodash is the simplest solution and as has been written is necessary because of the way objects are parsed. Mark that as the answer for the next person

Answer (score 0):

Because you edit the object in memory is the same reference, such as Array, Function and Object.

like this, use `Object.assign()`:

```
let obj1 = { a: 0 , b: { c: 0}};
let obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj1);
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj2)); // { a: 0, b: { c: 0}}
```

then edit `obj2`:

```
obj2.a = 33
console.log(obj1)  // { a: 0 , b: { c: 0}}
```

Comment: thanks for help, I try to format code but it didn't succeed